# Lowest screen resolution after closed laptop screen on external monitor

Tags: display-resolution

Ubuntu 16.04 automatically switches to the lowest screen resolution after I close my Laptop's screen on the external monitor and open it again.

My solution so far is:

> press [Fn+] F7

Anyway this is annoying, because I need my Laptop's keyboard. I don't know which event this is for Ubuntu. Sometimes, it occurs after login. I need to open my laptop and press F7 to reactivate the usual resolution.

Another way the system is wrong behaving is when I boot the system and login, the lowest screen resolution is used (the Laptop screen is closed all the time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears that I found a relative simple solution.

In Ubuntu system settings, I go to Display. There I can set my big external screen as default screen at startup (general configuration --> starter position --> change from [all] to your [external screen]).